# VB6, ACCESS 2002-2003, sometimes AUTONUMBER field is not generated

Tags: vb6, ms-access-2003, autonumber

Good morning. I developed an application 20 years ago using VB6 and Access 2002 2003. I have a table with an AUTONUMBER field and the following statements have always returned the value of the AUTONUMBER field (Progressivo_Tagliando).

```
Dim adoTaglInserimentoRS As Recordset
StmtInsert = "select * from Plico where Progressivo_Tagliando=0" 'No record have Progressivo_Tagliando=0, only to open RecordSet
adoTaglInserimentoRS.Open StmtInsert, db, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

VarCampiTagliando = Array("Nota", "Progressivo_Distinta", "Data_Stato_Plico", "Progressivo_Destinatario", "Progressivo_Corriere", "Contenuto_Plico", "Rifpr_Numsin", "Progressivo_Tramite", "Stato_Plico", "Username_Inserimento", "Data_Inserimento")

VarValoriTagliando = Array(adoTagliandoRSNote, adoTagliandoRSProgressivo_Distinta, adoTagliandoRSData_Stato_Plico, adoTagliandoRSProgressivo_Destinatario, adoTagliandoRSProgressivo_Corriere, adoTagliandoRSContenuto_Plico, adoTagliandoRSRifPr_NumSin, adoTagliandoRSProgressivo_Tramite, adoTagliandoRSStato_Plico, adoTagliandoRSUsername_Inserimento, adoTagliandoRSData_Inserimento)

db.BeginTrans
adoTaglInserimentoRS.AddNew VarCampiTagliando, VarValoriTagliando

txtPrg_Tagliando.Text = adoTaglInserimentoRS!Progressivo_Tagliando

adoTaglInserimentoRS.Close

db.CommitTrans
```

For a few days the AUTONUMBER value is sometimes generated and sometimes returns NULL and the instruction

```
txtPrg_Tagliando.Text = adoTaglInserimentoRS!Progressivo_Tagliando`
```

generates error.

I also tried using an `INSERT` instead of the `RecordSet`, then using a SELECT to find the max(AUTONUMBER), but even so it sometimes fails.

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure it's actually ending up null in the underlying record?  I've had issues when using `adOpenStatic`.  Does this occur when you switch that to `adOpenDynamic`?  Static is meant for read only recordsets, typically it's faster when you don't need to modify the record

Comment: Jimmy, thank you for your suggestion. Today is Saturday and the company is closed. Next Monday I will try to do what you suggested.

Comment: Jimmy, unfortunately nothing has changed.

Answer (score 2):

Like MS SQL, MS Access also supports the system function [@@IDENTITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

So after an INSERT do something like

```
' Retrieve new ID
sTable = "TheInsertTable"
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
sSQL = "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID FROM " & sTable & ";"
Call rs.Open(sSQL, gobjApp.DBCon)
ID = rs.Fields("ID").Value
Call rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
```

I never had a problem with it when using with an Access database (which also was Access 2003).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.
Statement
sSQL = "SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID FROM " & sTable & ";"
it makes sense if I have an IDENTITY field in the table, but it seems that the ACCESS syntax does not recognize the IDENTITY keyword.
I tried with the following syntax:
Create table PIPPO (C1 number identity(1,1), C2 number);
but it throws error on "identity".
I'm back to where I started.
​

Comment: To complete my previous comment I found (Bing AI): "Yes, it is possible to have an IDENTITY field in an MS Access 2002 and 2003 table. However, the term “IDENTITY” is not used in Access. Instead, it uses the term “AutoNumber” to indicate a field that automatically generates a unique numeric value for each record."

Comment: Yes, the AutoNumber property in Access is what makes that column an identity column. I assumed that was clear. I should have explained that. My bad. The above code is what I used with AutoNumber columns in Access.

Comment: Ok, now it's clearer.
Next weekend I will empty the table containing the AUTONUMBER field, I will compact the DB and reset the field, starting it from a much lower value (today we are at around 2023240000, I will start again from 1003000000).

Comment: I've noticed several times that  the Access engine may misbehave, often without error or warning.  It seems to particularly do this as the file size nears (but has not yet reached) the maximum 2gB (1gB for Access 1.x).  I wonder if the AutoNumber field approaching the similar limit (2^31, or 2147483648) is causing your issue, especially considering that it sounds like it occurs intermittently.  It will be interesting to hear if resetting the AutoNumber counter corrects the problem.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your input.
As regards the size of the .mdb file, today it is around 320Mb, therefore far from the limit you indicate.
Instead, the maximum value that we have approximately reached today (because as we write, the AUTONUMBER continues to be used until an error is generated) is that indicated in my previous comment.
As soon as I have COMPACT the .mdb and reset the AUTONUMBER, I will inform you how things are going, even if, being the error "random", "things will go well until they go bad!!!"

Comment: Unfortunately, the operation of compacting the db and restarting with a lower AUTONUMBER value was not successful.
I keep looking for a solution.